Validar si una consulta SQL regresa vacia o no existe el registro
me gustaría saber si me pueden ayudar con la posible solucion a mi problema, tengo la siguiente consukta sql:
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost; user=sa; 
password=test2023.; Initial Catalog=Articulos;");
conexion.Open();
string consulta = "select art.Articulo,Descripcion1,art.Unidad,round 
(ListaPreciosD.Precio,2) as Precio from art inner join ListaPreciosD on Art.Articulo = 
ListaPreciosD.Articulo where ListaPreciosD.Lista = '(Precio Lista)' and art.Estatus = 
'ALTA' and art.Articulo not like '%AF%' and art.Articulo = '" + prodcod.Text + "' ";
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
SqlDataReader lector;
lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
 if (lector.Read())
{
string preciounit;
articulo.Text = lector["Descripcion1"].ToString();
unidad.Text = lector["Unidad"].ToString();
preciounit = lector["Precio"].ToString();

double preciounita = Convert.ToDouble(preciounit);
preciou.Text = preciounita.ToString("N2");

}
conexion.Close();

Esto me trae la consulta a mis textbox, mi duda es cuando escriben un codigo de producto que tiene información se llena correctamente los textbox, ahora quisiera que cuando introducen un codigo de producto que no existe mueste el siguiente mensaje:
MessageBox.Show("El producto no existe");

Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo? tengo rato intentando pero no logro resolverlo :/
De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Según yo esa parte ya la tienes hecha, solo pon un else en tu if para mostrar el mensaje

Dios santo era tan sencillo que no lo probe!! Muchas gracias!!!

¿Conoces Bobby Tables? Tu código es vulnerable a inyección de código SQL. Deberías usar una consulta parametrizada para código de producto/artículo, en vez de concatenar la consulta SQL con lo que ha introducido el usuario

Es tal como @macx te lo dijo en su comentario, es solo agregar un else
Cuando haces:
SqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();

lector inicia en una posicion anterior al primer registro y la función Read(), lo que hace es retornar true si existe un próximo registro y a su vez se posiciona en ese próximo registro. En caso contrario retorna false.
Por este motivo Read() funciona tanto dentro de un if como de un while
if (lector.Read())
{
  string preciounit;
  articulo.Text = lector["Descripcion1"].ToString();
  unidad.Text = lector["Unidad"].ToString();
  preciounit = lector["Precio"].ToString();

  double preciounita = Convert.ToDouble(preciounit);
  preciou.Text = preciounita.ToString("N2");

}
else{
  MessageBox.Show("El producto no existe");
}


Si ya quedó, muchas gracias por la explicacion!
